# Increase thread count of Asyncspinner? (Multi-threading)

Tags: ros, c++, multi-thread, multi-robot, ros-jade

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I have a `world_node` which offers a service to `register_new_robot`.
Once called, the service creates a new C++ object from `Robot.cpp`.
This Robot object now sets up a few topics mainly for controlling the robot (e.g. `goToPose`) in its contructor.

Now the problem is, when I create the object in my `world_node` service callback, my whole `world_node` blocks. I already used AsyncSpinner for multi-threaded calls already (e.g. the topic listeners in `Robot`), but here is the problem:

The number of robots is changing, which means that I don't know for how many threads I have to set up AsyncSpinner.
The API does not offer adding a new thread, so what would you suggest to do? I could stop the spinner, create a new one with more threads, but that would cancel all the stuff currently done by the robots.
I could also have the Robot object be created in the a main of it's class file and simply create a new node. But that seems even more messy than what I already do.

I use jade. Please help me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228551/increase-thread-count-of-asyncspinner?-(multi-threading)/) by [Borob](https://answers.ros.org/users/23030/borob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2016-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Threads that don't have anything to do don't consume resources (well, the overhead is probably manageable). Is it an idea to set the nr of threads to some upper bound (say: 20)? Not really a solution ("640k is enough for everybody"), but would probably work well enough in practice.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0